# Why does the warehouse_report field value disappear in the form submission after using if statement in Laravel 8 forms?

Tags: php, forms, null, laravel-8, dcat

Dcat Admin dynamically displayed form with no value on submission

### Environment

Mac OS
Laravel: 8.83.27
PHP: 7.3

##Description
I use Form::make to generate a form, and part of the form is displayed by the parameters of the URL, for example, the parameter category_id=1 to display a form, to achieve dynamic form functionality.

The simplified code is as follows:
The warehouse_report field does not exist in the model Lease, but is set by me.

```php
 protected function form()
    {
        return Form::make(\App\Models\Lease::class, function (Form $form) {
            $categoryId = request()->get('category_id').
            if ($categoryId == 1) {
                $form->multipleImage('warehouse_report', 'validation report')->autoUpload()->uniqueName().
            }
   }).
    }
```

### Problem

When I load the page, upload the image and submit the form without using if, the warehouse_report field and its value exist in the submission load, but after using if, first setting the parameter in the URL to 2 (not displaying the form) and later setting it to 1 (displaying the form), then uploading the image and submitting the content, the value of the warehouse_report field in the load is empty. report field is empty
Why does this happen? How can I get the form to have a value?

### Screenshot

No judgment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiikY.png)

Submit with judgement
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SMYT.png)

PS: Why not use when for dynamic forms?
Because the form is required, the hidden form that is not used when submitting will prevent submission and have the same name column submission problem.

I tried to use if or no if judgement, and found that when no if judgement is used, the form is submitted with a value

Comment: _" if, first setting the parameter in the URL to 2 (not displaying the form) and later setting it to 1 (displaying the form)"_ - can you please clarify what what actually means? When and where are you "setting" this, during the whole process?

Comment: First I set the URL parameter category_id=2 in the browser, at this time the form was not displayed because the judgment was not valid, then I manually set category=1 and the browser was refreshed, at this time the judgment was successful and the form was displayed, then I uploaded the image and submitted the form